# Local media players won't play audio on movies

Tags: audio, media-player

I have a generic Android set top box. It works fine mostly, except it won't play audio for .avi, .mkv, mp4, etc. files. I can successfully hear audio on movies via NetFlix and YouTube, but if I download a movie, there's no audio.

I have tried multiple media players, including MX Player and VLC but neither works.

I haven't knowingly changed something to cause this. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: how is the audio encoded? Like AC3 or DTS? May be a codec problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android, MX Player, VLC do not have full codec compatibility due to licensing problems. I think the audio on your movies is an `ac3` or `dts` codec which is a 5.1 audio system, so it doesn't play natively on Android because Android uses 2.0 stereo. As I said, it can't be played natively, but there is a codec for MX Player that can play such audio formats. Follow those steps :

1. Go to [this thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player/mx-player-custom-codec-dts-support-t2156254)
2. Download the codec that matches your device's processor type (if you don't know which one to choose, search for an app called **Phone Info** on the Play Store. It will give you your device's type. Download the right codec)
3. Put the downloaded zip somewhere on your device. Example: `/sdcard/download/codec_arm_V7_neon`
4. Open MX Player and go to Setting > Decoder. Scroll all the way down and click Custom Codec, navigate to the downloaded zip location, and choose it
5. You may be asked to close and then reopen the MX Player, do so
6. You are good to go. Now your device can read AC3 and DTS sound format

Comment: I should note that the audio used to work on this device for the same files.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same file ? Because even if the extention is the same the codec might be different